# app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class

Tags: java, android, apache

**Error:** Execution failed for task `':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'`.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/apache/commons/logging/Log.class

in the modle gradle i use the  useLibrary **'org.apache.http.legacy'** and in my application gradle also use the  useLibrary **'org.apache.http.legacy'** so i think the question is the jar repetition ,but i have to use the  useLibrary **'org.apache.http.legacy**' who can solve the question? thanks!

Comment: `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` is enough. Check if other libraries do not use this lib

Comment: but the modle use http connect net is  'org.apache.http.legacy' ,you know how to use the application lib in the modle ,if can ,i think i can solve the question ,but i don't know how to reference